# Want to import data points from TDS3034C to Labview or Python

Tags: python, labview, oscilloscope

I've got my Techtronix TDS3034C Oscilloscope hooked up to my router and I know that my computer is able to read it because I'm able to access the waveform via my web browser; however, I need to write something that is able to receive the individual data points and output them to a text file. I'd like to be able to do this Labview,Python or otherwise. I hope that someone here has experience with this particular brand of oscilloscope. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

For Labview, you probably want to go to their [drivers download page](http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=13363) for that 'scope. To write your own software, you'll probably need to download [TekVisa](http://www2.tek.com/cmswpt/swdetails.lotr?ct=SW&cs=sut&ci=16449&lc=EN).

Answer (score 2):

You can find drivers for most Tek scopes (and others like HP, Agilent, etc) on NI's Instrument Driver Network:
[www.ni.com/idnet](http://www.ni.com/idnet)

As Jerry Coffin mentioned, the TDS3034C driver is also available there:
http://sine.ni.com/apps/utf8/niid_web_display.model_page?p_model_id=13363